# Azure API Managment: Is it possible to see trace when invoked from outside the portal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

from postman if I invoke the an IP which goes through API Management I set

> Ocp-Apim-Trace : True

. Will I be able to see the trace some where. Is this only ment to be used from inside the Test tab in API Management in azure portal?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you include the `Ocp-Apim-Trace` header with a value of `true`, a link to the trace file will be returned in the response header `Ocp-Apim-Trace-Location`, which you can open via Http

Pulling Vitaliy's comment up into the answer: the APIM subscription key needs to belong to a user who has admin rights in order for this to work

Comment: If subscription key is provided and that subscription belongs to Admin user.